# Add class to elements based on items inside of for loop in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I have a simple `for loop` that pulls from a `JSON` file in my `_data` folder. I want to be able to add a class to all the `H1s` if there are more than 3 titles and remove the class if there are less than 3 titles. I tried using conditional logic but doesn't seem to add the class to everything.

```
{% for book in site.data.books limit: 6 %}
    If > 3
        <h1 class="BookTitle {% if book.title > 3 %}BookTitleAlt{% endif %}>{{ book.title }}</h1>
    If < 3
        <h1 class="BookTitle">{{ book.title }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to get the size of an array is this `{% if book.size > 3 %}` but I have a feeling you want this instead

`{% if site.data.books.size > 3 %}`

Reference: https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/size/

Comment: Sorry, I may have jumped the gun. When I initially tested, I made the mistake of testing only on the item with 4 titles. When I checked other entries with 3 or less, your solution didn't work.

Comment: hi, does it work now? Can you clarify what the problem is?